# what to do with openid results?

Tags: openid

I am trying to use OpenID (JOpenID) for the first time. Once the OpenID auth is over and the return URL is called, i get the identity and email of the user. In case when the user opens my site in future, how do i identify the user again? Should i use cookie or something? Or does the OpenID take care of it? All OpenID libraries talk only about the login part, but nothing about remember the identity/where to store/what to store etc. Plz let me know where i can get the whole process of login using OpenID, remembering credentials and loggin out.

Answer (score -1):

The libraries only document the process of logging in, because that's what OpenID is. The rest should be done like with any other authentication scheme.

If you don't know how to do authentication without OpenID, then you won't know how to do it with OpenID (and your question should be "how to authenticate a user in language/framework X").

Comment: Since OpenID takes care of authentication it's not unreasonable to think it would also be involved in recognition of returning users.  The condescending second paragraph wasn't necessary.